# Why does normalization address precision problems in comparing doubles?

Tags: floating-point, precision, ieee-754

For the problem of computing the real square root of any given double value, the authors of Elements of Programming Interviews present a [solution](http://elementsofprogramminginterviews.com/solutions/cpp/square_root.cc) in which the difference between 2 double values `a` and `b` is computed as follows:

```
typedef enum { SMALLER, EQUAL, LARGER } Ordering;

Ordering Compare(double a, double b) {
  // Uses normalization for precision problem.
  double diff = (a - b) / b;
  return diff < -numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()
             ? SMALLER
             : diff > numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() ? LARGER : EQUAL;
}
```

**My questions are:**

1. What is the point of dividing by `b`? And how does this address "precision problems"?
2. I do not understand the significance of `epsilon()` in essence; the concept of the smallest value greater than 1. Why does it have its own constant in `numeric_limits` to begin with?

Comment: That's a rather odd solution. It looks as thought it was written by someone who (mistakenly) subscribes to the myth that you should never compare floats directly. There's absolutely no advantage to writing `if (Compare(mid_squared, x) == LARGER)` instead of `if (mid_squared > x)`.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the point of dividing by b

A number consists of mantissa and exponent (and sign, positive for sqrt). The `sqrt` function divides exponent by 2 and gets square root from mantissa. For example, sqrt(4e20) == 2e10; sqrt(4e-100) == 2e-50, and so on. Absolute error for them, considering IEEE754 double, is, respectively, near 1e-7 and 1e-67. So, any fixed absolute error is useless for comparing iterations; only relative error has sense. Dividing by `b` converts approximate absolute error to relative one.

One could use an alternative approach: split a source value into product of small value (e.g. between 1 and 4) and exponent; the latter would be restored to `sqrt` result at final. With such "normalized" input value, one can compare sequential root approximations with an absolute error.

> I do not understand the significance of epsilon() in essence; the concept of the smallest value greater than 1.

Not "the smallest value greater than 1", but difference between 1 and the former.

Using `epsilon` here suggests the approximate is one of two the closest ones (a smaller and a greater one) to the ideal rounded value. That is simpler than checking of the case precision doesn't increase but approximates fall into eternal loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt answer. I hope you don't mind me asking a couple of clarifying questions. When you say: "any absolute error is nonsense", what error are you referring to? Is it error in representing `a - b`? And why is absolute error nonsense in the case of `sqrt`?

Comment: Yes, a-b. I said an absolute error is nonsense because, for example, for `sqrt(2e100)` it shall (provided ieee754 "double") be near 1e33, but, for `sqrt(2e-100)` it shall be near 1e-67. So, you can't utilize a fixed value for the whole argument range. Instead, relative error does not substantially depend on argument exponent, and an algorithm can use the same value for any finite argument.

Comment: Is this to say that dividing `a - b` by `b` has the benefit of turning `a - b` into a _denormalized_ number, which - in IEEE 754 - has higher precision for values close to 0?

Comment: Of course it isn't. Denormalized numbers aren't of higher precision; they are of _less_ precision than normal ones, but higher than plain zero of implementations without denormalized numbers. But, denormalization of a-b is still not critical for the iterating sqrt() approach, because it doesn't spoil accuracy of existing approximations.

Answer (score -1):

The following post might give you some clear idea on why epsilon comparison is needed for your problem: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/